# How to search inside multiple <ul> elementsfor <li> with javascript

Tags: javascript

Very noob programer here. Im still in that weird fase where you use a lot of code from the internet and don't actaully know what to do with it. What i'm tring to do is: I have 2 `<ul>` elements (or multiple) and I want to be able to search inside each of them for a `<li>` element.

What is happening: The filter works only on the first `<ul>` element, not on the second.

I know i must create some sort of `for` to search first for all the `<ul>` elements and then search inside each of them. But i don't know how :(

Anyway, the code I'm using is this one below:

````
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Danielle</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Ernest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Eric</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Fabio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Frederick</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.document.querySelector(".myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body> ```
````

Comment: Note that using all caps is considered yelling in many sectors of the internet. You may want to [edit] your post if that is not your intent.

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey, I edit it

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector to go through all uls:

```
var uls = document.querySelectorAll("ul");

for(var x = 0; x < uls.length; x++){
    var lis = uls[x].querySelectorAll("li");
    for(var y = 0; y < lis.length; y++){
        var a = lis[y].querySelector('a');
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite simply in modern JavaScript and DOM:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // get all of the li elements that are contained by "myUL" elements
    document.querySelectorAll(".myUL li")
    // iterate over them 
      .forEach(l => l
      // toggle the "hidden" class on those li items that have
        .classList.toggle("hidden",
        // an anchor tag whose text includes the text typed into the textbox
          !l.querySelector("a").textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)));
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Danielle</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Ernest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Eric</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Fabio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Frederick</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! Super clean code and it worked perfectly!